# Invalid syntax python (defining vectors)

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
#define the balls velocity
ball1.velocity=vector(85*cos(pi/9),85*sin(pi/69,0)
ball2.velocity=vector(85*cos((2*pi)/9),85*sin((2*pi)/9),0)
ball3.velocity=vector(85*cos((4*pi)/9),85*sin((4*pi)/9),0)
```

It is saying that there is invalid syntax for "ball.2".  This has worked in previous programs and works for the other two balls. Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: depends on what ball2 object is.

Comment: Your code does not contain the text `ball.2`.  It contains `ball2`.  In any case, it looks like you're missing a parenthesis on the line above.

Comment: yes that is what i meant to type. thank you everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a closing parenthesis in the `ball1` line.